# i cant use full phone background on android

Tags: android, background, image-resizing

im just making a simple calculator app but when i create the ImageButton and add a image to them, they are forced to a certain spot and some get squished. My goal is to have the images on the left and right touch the edge of the screen with no gaps. link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOXTc.png

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/calculator_background">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_zero"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/button_decimal" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/button_negative" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/button_add" />
```

Comment: could you post your xml file please..this can help to modify your code better and exactly what you want...

Comment: there you go, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this lines

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

see you can use this layout for exact you required:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_zero" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_decimal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/button_negative" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_add"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: is this what you want?]

Comment: i've used linear layout for use as parent and four child relative layout that fits into parent by its weight.... the parent layout has total weightsum 4 so that fit...

Comment: dont forget mark answer as right answer if its working tharefore it helps in future for someone else also..

Comment: what is the errors??? errors are only with your  background for which you have to replace with yours ...Remove toggle button if not required.. and still have error then give error lines code

Comment: see edited answer.... that removes src and putted with your drawable names... chekout